# #Win10/Iron Cannot get message of "INFO custom_minimal_param_node: Hello earth!" after using the launch file

Tags: ros2, tutorial, parameter, windows, windows10

guys!
I am learning about [《Using parameters in a class (Python) — ROS 2 Documentation: Iron documentation》](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-Python.html).

For the section of [[3.2 Change via a launch file]](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Using-Parameters-In-A-Class-Python.html#change-via-a-launch-file), after running the

```bash
ros2 launch python_parameters python_parameters_launch.py
```

The CMD console did not print the "[INFO] [custom_minimal_param_node]: Hello earth!", as

```bash
D:\ros2_ws>ros2 launch python_parameters python_parameters_launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\songyuc\.ros\log\2023-08-28-14-26-13-306213-DESKTOP-OB91EPG-21596
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [minimal_param_node.EXE-1]: process started with pid [6008]
```

, and it just stuck there with no action.

Relevant:

- I have installed all the dependencies require from the tutorial.
- The codes used are just copied from the tutorial.

The files in `D:\ros2_ws\src>` are listed below:

```bash
D:\ros2_ws\src>dir
 驱动器 D 中的卷是 文档
 卷的序列号是 A009-7878

 D:\ros2_ws\src 的目录

2023/08/28  13:48    <DIR>          .
2023/08/28  13:48    <DIR>          ..
2023/08/21  20:19    <DIR>          build
2023/08/28  13:29    <DIR>          cpp_parameters
2023/08/16  16:57    <DIR>          cpp_pubsub
2023/08/21  20:29    <DIR>          cpp_srvcli
2023/08/21  20:19    <DIR>          log
2023/08/21  20:55    <DIR>          more_interfaces
2023/08/16  16:21    <DIR>          my_package
2023/08/28  14:04    <DIR>          python_parameters
2023/08/28  13:48    <DIR>          python_parameters_template
2023/08/21  20:15    <DIR>          py_pubsub
2023/08/21  19:35    <DIR>          py_srvcli
2023/08/16  15:03    <DIR>          ros_tutorials
2023/08/21  19:52    <DIR>          tutorial_interfaces
               0 个文件              0 字节
              15 个目录 482,137,817,088 可用字节

D:\ros2_ws\src>
```

Platform: Win10

Python: 3.8.3

ROS distribution: Iron

Could you please help me solve this problem?